# Object is of type "unknown" in interfaces

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm creating project in Laravel 8 + Vue 3 with Typescript and Inertia

I got this error all the time

`TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.`

on this code

`console.log(usePage().props.value.auth.user);`

There is my auth and user interface:

```
export interface UserInterface {
    id: number
    name: string
    email: string
}

export interface AuthInterface {
    user?: UserInterface
}
```

When I `console.log` without `.user`, everythink is fine.

There is my `usePage` function:

```
import {usePage as inertiaUsePage} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

export const usePage = () => {
    return inertiaUsePage<PageProps>();
}

export interface PageProps {
    auth: AuthInterface
}
```

Comment: You need to include `usePage` return type as well to properly tell you what's the issue

Comment: I added my usePage function

Answer (score 0):

You can add any as a type, this will replace unknown type:

```
usePage<any>()
```

Answer (score -1):

I've reproduced your error, and I found that you also need to have `vue3` & `@inertiajs/inertia` installed for types to be correct.

Comment: There is typing by default, i don't find any packages for vue3 or inertia typings.

Comment: `yarn add vue@3 @inertiajs/inertia`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help